# CAKE PHP　bakeで仕上げた画面に生じたエラーの内容を把握したい

Tags: cakephp

CAKEPHPに手を出して間もないものです。本日初めてbakeというものを実行してみて、一応に成功した模様です(controller~model~templateが仕上がる)

テーブル名を指定したbakeコマンドだけで、登録・編集・カード型照会画面・ページインデックス付きのリスト画面が仕上がったことは非常に魅力的でした。

===質問===
登録画面を試行したところ、下記のようにエラーを招きました。具体的な要因を知りたいのですが、どこかに書かれているものでしょうか？
ちなみにDataBaseはMSSQLです。（これが関係しているのかなぁ．．．）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

===追記===
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: PHPを動かしているコンソールのログの内容を貼り付けてみてください

Comment: ncaq、お時間を頂き誠にありがとうございます。
超初心者で分かりが悪くて申し訳ありません。
仰られているコンソールのログとは、phpフォルダ内のphp_error.logのことを指されていますか？？

cakephpの内臓サーバとやらで実行しているので（http://localhost:8765/となっているのはそのため）
上記ログファイルには記載されていないようだし．．．。
これかな？と思って本文に貼り付けたログは如何でしょう？何も表示されていませんが。

引き続きご見解を頂けたら幸いです、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: CakePHPのログです.そちらの構成がどうなっているのか今ひとつわからないのですが,log/debug.log, tmp/log/debug.log, syslog, journaldなどにログは出力されていませんか?

Comment: ncaq様、お付き合いを頂き誠にありがとうございます。
logsフォルダ配下のファイルを確認しましたが記録なし。tmpフォルダ配下は該当ファイルなし
syslogとjournaldというファイルは見当たりませんでした。

DataBase定義のapp.php内Datasourcesの部分で'log' => false,になっているのは関係ありますかね？？
何から何まですみません

Comment: 参考までに、画像のDebugKitのLogパネルは、Cake経由で出力されるログ(logs/error.log, logs/debug.log等)の内容が見れるようになっています。何か問題があるとき、まずここを見るのはよい習慣です。Datasources.logの設定は、DBサーバーに発行されるSQLをログに記録するかの設定です。通常はfalseで問題ありません。

Comment: @nojimage とても有用な情報をありがとうございます。
今後の活動に役立てていきたいと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bakeを使用して作成したのであれば、"The book could not be saved. Please, try again."というメッセージは、保存失敗時のメッセージとなります。

保存失敗の理由は、モデル(`BooksTable`)に定義されたバリデーションが通らなかったか、データベースへの書き込みに失敗したかとなります。データベースへの書き込みに失敗した場合は、基本的には例外が発生しますので上記のような表示にはなりません。

今回の場合は、バリデーションエラーによる保存失敗の可能性が高いです。
バリデーションエラーは、保存対象のエンティティオブジェクト（今回であれば`$book`）に記録されていますので、これを確認します。

DebugKitを導入しているのであれば、「Variables」のパネルでテンプレートに渡されている変数の内容が見れますのでこれを利用します。
DebugKitのツールバーから「Variables」を開いて、`book`→`errors`を確認してみてください。

Comment: なお、VariablesタブはTimersの右ですので、DebugKitツールバーの左にある「>」をクリックすると出てきます。

Comment: この度は色々とありがとうございました。
まさにご提示の方法で要因を把握することができました。
（Primaryキーの項目が入っていないらしい。MySQLで試行したときは大丈夫だったんだけれど）
CakePHPを内臓サーバで実行した際に現われる右下のケーキマークのメニュー、パネルというのですね。
これさえも初めて知り、成長することができました。重ねて御礼を申し上げます。